# Spark, kerberos, yarn-cluster -> connection to hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, kerberos

Facing one issue with Kerberos enabled Hadoop cluster.

We are trying to run a streaming job on yarn-cluster, which interacts with Kafka (direct stream), and hbase.

Somehow, we are not able to connect to hbase in the cluster mode. We use keytab to login to hbase.

This is what we do:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --keytab "dev.keytab" --principal "dev@IO-INT.COM"  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_executor_conf.properties -XX:+UseG1GC" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_driver_conf.properties -XX:+UseG1GC" --conf spark.yarn.stagingDir=hdfs:///tmp/spark/ --files "job.properties,log4j_driver_conf.properties,log4j_executor_conf.properties" service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar job.properties
```

To connect to hbase:

```
def getHbaseConnection(properties: SerializedProperties): (Connection, UserGroupInformation) = {


    val config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_VALUE);
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", 2181);
    config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    config.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    config.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true");
    config.set("hbase.rpc.protection", "privacy");
   config.set("hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal", “hbase/_HOST@IO-INT.COM”);
    config.set("hbase.master.kerberos.principal", “hbase/_HOST@IO-INT.COM”);

    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);

     var ugi: UserGroupInformation = null;
      if (SparkFiles.get(properties.keytab) != null
        && (new java.io.File(SparkFiles.get(properties.keytab)).exists)) {
        ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(properties.kerberosPrincipal,
          SparkFiles.get(properties.keytab));
      } else {
        ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(properties.kerberosPrincipal,
          properties.keytab);
      }


    val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
    return (connection, ugi);
  }
```

and we connect to hbase:
 ….

```
foreachRDD { rdd =>
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        //var ugi: UserGroupInformation = Utils.getHbaseConnection(properties)._2
        rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>
          val connection = Utils.getHbaseConnection(propsObj)._1
          val table = …
          partition.foreach { json =>

          }
          table.put(puts)
          table.close()
          connection.close()
        }
      }
    }
```

Keytab file is not getting copied to yarn staging/temp directory, we are not getting that in SparkFiles.get… and if we pass keytab with --files, spark-submit is failing because it’s there in --keytab already.

Comment: Spark uses `--principal` / `--keytab` (or the matching properties `spark.yarn.principal` / `.keytab`) internally, you should not have to care about the UGI in your code. And since Spark 1.4 the Launcher should obtain an "HBase token" *before* the driver even starts, and broadcast it to the executors -- the `hbase-spark` library (contributed by Cloudera) provides an wrapper that manages the "token" automatically on executor side, so you should give it a try...

Comment: BTW the **actual error messages** would be much more useful than your source code -- that, and also the actual Spark version.

Comment: Versions:scala: 2.10.5
spark: 1.6.0
hbase-client: 1.2.0

Comment: Initially we were getting: because it was not able to get keytab from SparkFiles.

org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: Login failure for user: dev@IO-INT.COM from keytab dev.keytab javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI

if we remove loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI, assuming internally it will be taken care of

we started getting:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list hbase

Comment: Again, why don't you use the HBase API that was specifically created for Spark??? http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_basic_spark

Comment: How you manage authorization and principal renewal ? Do you have principal domain server ?

Answer (score 0):

error is:

```
This server is in the failed servers list: myserver.test.com/120.111.25.45:60020
RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1497943263013, pause=100, retries=5}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: myserver.test.com/120.111.25.45:60020
RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1497943263013, pause=100, retries=5}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: myserver.test.com/120.111.25.45:60020 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:935)
```